# Securing ROS Based Robots & The Cloud

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I'm interested in building a series of ROS based robots that will need to be connected to some form of cloud based storage. This is to query user parameters (someone will be able to sign up for an account, and when they walk up to our robot, like a kiosk, they'll be able to log in and have a customized experience). I saw [this post](http://answers.ros.org/question/107006/security-vulnerabilities-in-ros/), and am trying to design the best way to protect user data. This user data would be stored during execution as parameters. The sensor data would be stored in a bag, compressed and stored on this cloud storage instance.

Since no actual computation is being distributed, and the ROS system and cloud system will never interact directly, is there a way to lock down the port of the ROS_MASTER_URI, so that it can only be used internally? Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/203840/securing-ros-based-robots-&-the-cloud/) by [aak2166](https://answers.ros.org/users/21299/aak2166/) on ROS Answers with karma: 593 on 2015-02-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can't you just block the outbound traffic from the master with an internal firewall?

---

Originally posted by [Mr. CEO](https://answers.ros.org/users/21719/mr.-ceo/) with karma: 143 on 2015-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1